# When calculating absolute magnitudes of distant objects, do you use the light-travel distance or the comoving distance?

Tags: galaxy, redshift, apparent-magnitude, absolute-magnitude

I want to calculate the absolute magnitude of GN-z11. Its light-travel distance is 13.4 billion ly (4.1 Gpc), its comoving distance is 32 billion ly (9.8 Gpc), and its apparent magnitude is $25.8$. Calculating its absolute magnitude, we get $M=-76.86$ for light-travel, and $M=-94.09$ for comoving. Which one do I use? I am assuming it is the former. Is this correct, or is there a different formula for this?

Answer (score 3):

Neither. You use the [Luminosity Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminosity_distance).

$$M = m -5\log D_L + 5$$

This assumes bolometric magnitudes. If you are trying to estimate it in some photometric band then you must also calculate and apply a [K-correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_correction) that will depend upon the intrinsic spectrum of the source.

For $z=11.09$ [this cosmology calculator](https://home.fnal.gov/%7Egnedin/cc/) gives a model-dependent luminosity-distance modulus of 50.39 (corresponding to $D_L=1.2\times 10^{11}$ pc).

NB: The distances you quote in the question do not give the absolute magnitudes quoted.